# When to use concat and append?

Tags: java, string

I started learning java and always had this bugging my mind.
When to use concat() and when to use append() operations.
Do they perform the same operation and what of their return types?

Comment: When you read these methods their documentation, what did that tell you? Where does the confusion stem from? Can you share your research so we don't have to do the same?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel has the key -- always read the API documentation first.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a careful reading of javadocs should have been sufficient.

Comment: If you're building a *large* string one piece at a time, use `StringBuilder` and its `append()` method. Otherwise use the string concatenation operator `+`, e.g. `res = str1 + str2`. The truth is that the performance different compared to `res = str1.concat(str2)` is so minuscule, that it's meaningless, and the `concat()` method is an obsolete holdover from ancient times. I've never used it, and I can't remember ever seeing any open-source code using it, so just forget that it even exists.

Answer (score 4):

**concat():**

- String has a concat method, string is immutable.
- adds a string to another string.
- It will create the new object after concatenation is done, since it is a immutable.

**append():**

- StringBuilder and StringBuffer has append method, these two are mutable.
- appends a char or char sequence to a string.
- It will not create a new object, since it is a mutable one.